# Determine if window belongs to desktop or Windows Store app

Tags: windows, desktop, hwnd

There are traditional desktop applications and Windows Store apps on the screen. I have their HWNDs. Can I determine what type of windows they are (Desktop or Store apps) based on their HWNDs?

Answer (score 0):

Use GetClassName() to get the class name of the applications

When a windows store app's window is in foreground and not minimized : class name = ApplicationFrameWindow
When a windows store app's window is in foreground and minimized : class name = windows.UI.Core.coreWindow
when a windows store app's windows is closed or in background: They are listed as two windows  class name = ApplicationFrameWindow and class name = windows.UI.Core.coreWindow.